# Notifications don't fire to correct app

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, ios-app, stack-overflow-app

According to [the announcement](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/16/stack-overflow-official-app-launches-ios-android/?cb=1), if you have both the Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow apps, your notifications for Stack Overflow should come into the Stack Overflow app.

> If you decide to download both apps, your notifications will be split between the two. Your Stack Overflow notifications will appear in the Stack Overflow app, and all other Stack Exchange notifications will appear in the Stack Exchange app.

I have both installed, just received a Stack Overflow notification and it came into the Stack Exchange app. An additional notification came into the Stack Overflow app. Perhaps there's some state not being properly transferred?

Stack Exchange iOS App: v.1.6.5.4
Stack Overflow iOS App: v.1.0

Comment: The version info is available in the App Store.  I have edited your question to reflect the correct version.

Comment: Can confirm, both apps receive a Stack Overflow notification

Comment: I'll try to reproduce this issue on Android (SE: 1.0.92 / SO: 1.0)

Comment: @ChrisForrence have you got the result on the Android? ;)

Comment: @AndrewT. Well, I received this only on the SE app! Still looking for a notification on Stack Overflow proper; it looks like Meta Stack Overflow would not be covered by the Stack Overflow app...?

Comment: @ChrisForrence oops, I forgot that the current SO app doesn't cover MSO... sorry =/

Comment: @AndrewT. It's alright, find me on Stack Overflow and mention me ;)

Comment: Thanks @AndrewT.! I received the notification only on the SO app (looks to work properly), so it looks like this bug may only affect the iOS apps.

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in 1.0.1.2 and 1.6.6.2 when both are installed.

It appears that on some devices, under some circumstances, the two apps will have different values for `UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor`.  This is the indicator we were using to evaluate whether or not two apps were on the same device.

Going forward, we will use a unique identifier stored in their shared keychain.